# Change account password remotely via Plink

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-16.04, password, remote, plink

Here's my current predicament: I need to change the password to a user account on 2000 devices running Ubuntu 16.04.  I want to do this remotely via Plink rather than SSH.
On all these appliances, the username is `TESTUSER` and password is `TESTPASS`. In short, they all have the same username and password.

Plink script executed via CMD: `FOR /F "tokens=1,2* delims=," %G IN (C:\Users\username\Desktop\TEST\Device_IPs.txt) DO echo y | plink -v -ssh -m "C:\Users\username\Desktop\TEST\commands.txt" TESTUSER@%G -pw TESTPASS >> Results.txt 2>&1`

In my commands.txt file is
`echo TESTUSER:TESTPASSNEW | chpasswd`

The above command works via SSH flawlessly but only with elevated sudo privileges.  In other words:

1. SSH to device
2. `sudo -i`
3. Input `TESTPASS` as password
4. Run `echo TESTUSER:TESTPASSNEW | chpasswd`

`TESTPASSNEW` is what I'd like to change the password to.
Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Why do you ssh as one user and then switch to the other user?

Comment: Small correction: I simply do a sudo -i then I run the command not with TESTUSER@Hostname but with root@Hostname.  But I cannot SSH to the device using root/password method.  I have a less than novice understanding of Linux but hoping people smarter than I am understand what's going on

Comment: Why not put the commands in a .sh file, then download and run the file with plink?